# Pass MySQL Variable to Joomla Module instead of using default field for Twitter Search

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

It seems I've hit a wall here and could use some help

Would like to pass a MySql variable to a Joomla Module

Im using Yootheme's Widget-kit to display tweets from a search term. Works great and all but you need to enter the twitter search term in the Module back end.

Instead I would like to use a variable ( already used on the page) and pass that variable to the Twitter module so it can display the tweets I want

Here are some lines of PHP with the variable I'd like to use

```
$document->setTitle(JText::sprintf('COVERAGE_DATA_PLACE', $this->country->country_name,     $this->city->city_name));

$text = JString::str_ireplace('%city_name%',$this->city->city_name,$text);

$this->setBreadcrumbs(array('country','city'));
```

Is there any way to take the "City" variable and send it to the 'word" field found in the twitter module?

Here is the Code for the twitter module

```
<?php

Class: TwitterWidgetkitHelper
    Twitter helper class
*/
class TwitterWidgetkitHelper extends WidgetkitHelper {

/* type */
public $type;

/* options */
public $options;

/*
    Function: Constructor
        Class Constructor.
*/
public function __construct($widgetkit) {
    parent::__construct($widgetkit);

    // init vars
    $this->type    = strtolower(str_replace('WidgetkitHelper', '', get_class($this)));
    $this->options = $this['system']->options;

    // create cache
    $cache = $this['path']->path('cache:');
    if ($cache && !file_exists($cache.'/twitter')) {
        mkdir($cache.'/twitter', 0777, true);
    }

    // register path
    $this['path']->register(dirname(__FILE__), $this->type);
}

/*
    Function: site
        Site init actions

    Returns:
        Void
*/
public function site() {

    // add translations
    foreach (array('LESS_THAN_A_MINUTE_AGO', 'ABOUT_A_MINUTE_AGO', 'X_MINUTES_AGO', 'ABOUT_AN_HOUR_AGO', 'X_HOURS_AGO', 'ONE_DAY_AGO', 'X_DAYS_AGO') as $key) {
        $translations[$key] = $this['system']->__($key);
    }

    // add stylesheets/javascripts
    $this['asset']->addFile('css', 'twitter:styles/style.css');
    $this['asset']->addFile('js', 'twitter:twitter.js');
    $this['asset']->addString('js', sprintf('jQuery.trans.addDic(%s);', json_encode($translations)));

    // rtl
    if ($this['system']->options->get('direction') == 'rtl') {
        $this['asset']->addFile('css', 'twitter:styles/rtl.css');
    }

}

/*
    Function: render
        Render widget on site

    Returns:
        String
*/
public function render($options) {

    if ($tweets = $this->_getTweets($options)) {

        // get options
        extract($options);

        return $this['template']->render("twitter:styles/$style/template", compact('tweets', 'show_image', 'show_author', 'show_date', 'image_size'));
    }

    return 'No tweets found.';
}

/*
    Function: _getURL
        Create Twitter Query URL

    Returns:
        String
*/
protected function _getURL($options) {

    // get options
    extract($options);

    // clean options
    foreach (array('from_user', 'to_user', 'ref_user', 'word', 'nots', 'hashtag') as $var) {
        $$var = preg_replace('/[@#]/', '', preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', trim($$var)));
    }

    // build query
    $query = array();

    if ($from_user) {
        $query[] = 'from:'.str_replace(' ', ' OR from:', $from_user);
    }

    if ($to_user) {
        $query[] = 'to:'.str_replace(' ', ' OR to:', $to_user);
    }

    if ($ref_user) {
        $query[] = '@'.str_replace(' ', ' @', $ref_user);
    }

    if ($word) {
        $query[] = $word;
    }

    if ($nots) {
        $query[] = '-'.str_replace(' ', ' -', $nots);
    }

    if ($hashtag) {
        $query[] = '#'.str_replace(' ', ' #', $hashtag);
    }

    $limit = min($limit ? intval($limit) : 5, 100);

    // build timeline url
    if ($from_user && !strpos($from_user, ' ') && count($query) == 1) {

        $url = 'http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/'.strtolower($from_user).'.json';

        if ($limit > 15) {
            $url .= '?count='.$limit;
        }

        return $url;
    }

    // build search url
    if (count($query)) {

        $url = 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q='.urlencode(implode(' ', $query));

        if ($limit > 15) {
            $url .= '&rpp='.$limit;
        }

        return $url;
    }

    return null;    
}

/*
    Function: _getTweets
        Get Tweet Object Array

    Returns:
        Array
*/
protected function _getTweets($options) {

    // init vars
    $tweets = array();

    // query twitter
    if ($url = $this->_getURL($options)) {
        if ($path = $this['path']->path('cache:twitter')) {
            $file = rtrim($path, '/').sprintf('/twitter-%s.php', md5($url));

            // is cached ?
            if (file_exists($file)) {
                $response = file_get_contents($file);
            }

            // refresh cache ?
            if (!file_exists($file) || (time() - filemtime($file)) > 300) {

                // send query
                $request = $this['http']->get($url);

                if (isset($request['status']['code']) && $request['status']['code'] == 200) {
                    $response = $request['body'];
                    file_put_contents($file, $response);
                }
            }
        }
    }


    // create tweets
    if (isset($response)) {

        $response = json_decode($response, true);

        if (is_array($response)) {

            if (isset($response['results'])) {
                foreach ($response['results'] as $res) {

                    $tweet = new WidgetkitTweet();
                    $tweet->user = $res['from_user'];
                    $tweet->name = $res['from_user'];
                    $tweet->image = $res['profile_image_url'];
                    $tweet->text = $res['text'];
                    $tweet->created_at = $res['created_at'];
                    $tweets[] = $tweet;
                }
            } else {
                foreach ($response as $res) {

                    $tweet = new WidgetkitTweet();
                    $tweet->user = $res['user']['screen_name'];
                    $tweet->name = $res['user']['name'];
                    $tweet->image = $res['user']['profile_image_url'];
                    $tweet->text = $res['text'];
                    $tweet->created_at = $res['created_at'];

                    $tweets[] = $tweet;
                }
            }

        }
    }

    return array_slice($tweets, 0, $options['limit'] ? intval($options['limit']) : 5);
}

}


class WidgetkitTweet {

public $user;
public $name;
public $image;
public $text;
public $created_at;

public function getLink() {
    return 'http://twitter.com/'.$this->user;           
}

public function getText() {

    // format text
    $text = preg_replace('@(https?://([-\w\.]+)+(/([\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?(#\S+)?)?)?)@', '<a href="$1">$1</a>', $this->text);
    $text = preg_replace('/@(\w+)/', '<a href="http://twitter.com/$1">@$1</a>', $text);
    $text = preg_replace('/\s+#(\w+)/', ' <a href="http://search.twitter.com/search?q=%23$1">#$1</a>', $text);

    return $text;           
}

}

// bind events
$widgetkit = Widgetkit::getInstance();
$widgetkit['event']->bind('site', array($widgetkit['twitter'], 'site'));
```

Comment: Anyone? If there is something Im missing that can help please let me know

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can do what you want with this:
http://www.j-plant.com/joomla-extensions/free-extensions/26-module-plant.html

> This plugin supports module parameters overriding. Use the next code
>   for overriding parameters:
>
> `[moduleplant id="77" <param_name_1>="<param_value_1>"  <param_name_N>="<param_value_N>"]`
>   replace  and  with the necessary parameter name and value. 
>   You can override as many parameters as you want. 
>   Available module parameters can be found in module XML manifest
>   file. A manifest file is usually located in the next path:
>
> ```
> modules/<module_type>/<module_type>.xml
> ```